# For an elliptic curve, what is the difference between the base field modulus $Q$ and subgroup $r$

Tags: elliptic-curves, finite-field

What is the difference between the basefield modulus $Q$ and a subgroup of prime order $r$?

They are all fields, but what is their relevance to the curve they are defined upon?

How does this relate to a scalar field?

Also: Which field is the curve defined upon?

Comment: Link to interesting discussion that stemmed from this with kelalaka: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88187/discussion-between-kelalaka-and-wecanbefriends

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking about a subset of Elliptic Curve (EC) domain parameters over $\mathbb{F}_p$ or $\mathbb{F}_{2^m}$

Domain parameters of Elliptic Curves over $\mathbb{F}_p$ is the sextuple:

$$T= (p,a,b,G,n,h)$$

- The integer $p$ defines the field $\mathbb{F}_p$,
- $a$ and $b$ defines the curve equation in Weierstrass form: 
  $$E: y^2 \equiv x^3 + a \cdot x + b \pmod{p}$$
- $G=(x_g,y_g)$ defines the base point
- a prime $n$ which is order of $G$
- and an integer $h = \#E(\mathbb{F}_p)/n$

So, first choose an EC, then we choose a $G$ that generates a subgroup of order $n$.

> They are all fields, but what is their relevance to the curve they are defined upon?

EC is an Algebraic Group but it is defined over the Field $\mathbb{F}_p$

> How does this relate to a scalar field?

We have scalar ([point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication)) multiplication to represent the $k$ addition of a point $P$ by itself as $kP$.

> Which field is the curve defined upon?

Above $\mathbb{F}_p$, it can be also $\mathbb{F}_{2^m}$, but these are for general Cryptographic purposes. EC's can be defined over the [Complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve#Elliptic_curves_over_the_complex_numbers), too.